# javascript countdown timer with sql time from database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, pdo

i have this code countdown javascript is work fine :

```
<div id="countdown"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#countdown').countdown('2017/07/11 06:32:11', function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
      });

    });                                
</script>
```

but after get the time from database don't work this is the code after get time from database countdown don't show in id countdown

```
    <?php 
    $auc  = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `auction` WHER ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $auc->execute(); 
    $row = $auc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>


    <div id="countdown"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#countdown').countdown(<?php echo $row['timeauc']; ?>, function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
      });

    });                                
    </script>
```

Comment: So what javascript code does the PHP code produce?

Comment: What is the actual value of <?php echo $row['timeauc']; ?>?

Comment: `WHER ` is wrong, but also how is it stored in the db? not like 2017/07/11 06:32:11 i hope

Comment: You need to put quotes around where you are printing the date otherwise it's going to end up like: `countdown(2017/07/11 06:32:11,` which is syntactically wrong, you should see a syntax error in your developer tools console

Comment: @Mike is 2017/07/11 06:32:11

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  fixed sql code and value is 2017/07/11 06:32:11 in database but doesn't show in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a pair of quotes missing:

```
$('#countdown').countdown("<?php echo $row["timeauc"]; ?>", function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
});
```

But, to avoid a potential cross-site scripting vulnerability, you should escape the value instead:

```
$('#countdown').countdown(<?php echo json_encode($row["timeauc"]); ?>, function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
});
```

If nothing is showing up, first make sure `$row["timeauc"]` actually contains the date string:

```
var_dump($row["timeauc"]);
```